# How include Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have the application on the WP7 when I run it on the WP8 fails

*The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' exists in both 'e:..................\lib\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll'*

The Windows Phone Toolkit I set. Can anyone knows how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/96743). It's been refactored (with LongListSelector removed, etc.) to work with WP8 SDK. Update toolkit and try to use built-in LongListSelector from SDK.

Comment: Thank you.  I found my mistake. In the project I have a folder library, there lay the old dll toolkit, to it my application addressed. I replaced it with a new, and application worked